# Question on C program that reverses an unsigned integers bits

Tags: c, reverse, bit

Hi all I am writing a C program that asks the user for an unsigned integer. The program will then call a function
unsigned int reverse_bits(unsigned int n)
This function should return an unsigned integer whose bits are the same as those of n but in reverse
order.
Print to screen the integer whose bits are in reverse order.

Example:

User enters:
12   (binary 16 bits is 0000000000001100)

Program print to screen:
12288   (0011000000000000)

This is the code i have but it does not output the right answer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

//function prototype
unsigned int reverse_bits(unsigned int n);


int main(void) {
    unsigned int n;
    unsigned int bits;

    printf("Enter an unsigned integer: ");
    scanf("%u",&n);
    
    bits = reverse_bits(n);
    
    printf("%u\n",bits);

    return 0;
}

unsigned int reverse_bits(unsigned int n) {
    unsigned int reverse = 0;
    while (n > 0) {
            reverse = reverse << 1;
            if((n & 1) == 1) {
                    reverse = reverse | 1;
            }
            n = n >> 1;
    }
    return reverse;
}
```

This does not give me 12288 when I enter 12, it gives me 3, what did I do wrong?

Comment: Don't stop when n is zero, but run for the number of bits you have in an unsigned int. Or add an additional shift at the end (but it's harder).

Comment: An unsigned integer is usually not 16 bits though.

Comment: A loop such as `(for int i = 0; i < 8 * sizeof n; i++)` instead of the `while` loop.

Answer (score 3):

The result depends on how many bits an `unsigned int` is stored on your machine. It is usually 4 bytes (32 bits). So, in your case `12` (`00000000000000000000000000001100` in binary) becames `805306368` (`00110000000000000000000000000000` in binary).

Apart from that, you need to iterate over all bits of an `unsigned int`:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(unsigned int) * 8; i++) {
    reverse = reverse << 1;
    if((n & 1) == 1) {
        reverse = reverse | 1;
    }
    n = n >> 1;
}
```

Comment: You might be able to make it faster by changing the innermost block to: reverse = reverse << 1 | (n & 1); n >>= 1;   This saves a test and conditional.  You could also consider doing more than one bit in the loop:  reverse = (reverse<<3) | (unsigned char)("\000\\004\002\006\001\005\003\007"[n&7]; n <<= 3;